# Find imaginary part of complex expression

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates

Given the system of ODEs, $$x'=x^3-3xy^2$$ $$y'=3x^2 y-y^3,$$ it can be shown that the system may be written as $z'=z^3$, where $z=x+iy$. However, I don't seem to get how to show that $\Im m\{\frac{1}{z^2}\}$ is constant. Moreover, this fact can somehow be used to sketch the phase portrait.

The "best" I've so far come up with is this:

$(\frac{1}{z^2})'=-\frac{2z'}{z^3}=-2 \implies \frac{1}{z^2}=-2t$

We can also use polar coordinates, but the question is where and how exactly?

I'd appreciate some clarification. This is truly new to me.

Comment: By almost what you wrote, $1/z^2=-2t+C$. Now take the imaginary part. (We have $C=D+Ei$.)

Comment: Actually, the solutions are $\frac1{z^2}=\frac1{z_0^2}-2t$, not $\frac1{z^2}=-2t$, hence, indeed, $\Im\left(\frac1{z^2}\right)=\Im\left(\frac1{z_0^2}\right)$ is constant. Thus, each solution stays on the curve of equation $\Im(\bar z^2/|z|^4)=-2c$ for some suitable $c$, that is, the curve of equation $xy=c(x^2+y^2)^2$.

Comment: @Did: Can you please clarify why each solution stays on $\Im\{\bar{z}^2/|z|^4\}=-2c$, and where is the equation $xy=c(x^2+y^2)^2$ coming from?

Comment: 1. $1/z^2=\bar z^2/|z|^4$. 2. $\Im(\bar z^2/|z|^4)=\Im(\bar z^2)/|z|^4$. 3. $|z|^4=(x^2+y^2)^2$. 4. $\bar z^2=x^2-y^2-2ixy$.

Comment: $\frac{\Im\{\bar{z}^2\}}{|z|^4}=\frac{-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$. Where is the $-2c$ and $xy=c(x^2+y^2)^2$ coming from?

Comment: ?? Sorry but you lost me: you have $\Im(\bar z^2)/|z|^4$ as a function of $(x,y)$ and you know this is a constant, say $-2c$, but you cannot deduce the identity $xy=c\cdot(x^2+y^2)^2$?

Comment: Sorry, I had gotten confused, now that part is clear, thanks. Can you please explain why the fact that $\Im\{\frac{1}{z^2}\}$ is constant implies that all solutions stay on this curve? I'm trying to understand the peculiar connection here.

Comment: I can see here that $\frac{\bar{z}^2}{|z|^4}$ is a normalization of $\bar{z}^2$. Then we can the imaginary part of it, which is a constant, and we also deduce the equation, and so we have level curves. What I'm not seeing here is why just the imaginary part determines the curves. Seems a bit tricky.

Comment: $$\Im\left(\frac1{(x+iy)^2}\right)=\frac{-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$